# Steam market API returns null

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

For very long time I've used request like this:
[steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview](http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=RU&currency=5&appid=440&market_hash_name=Strange%20Sole%20Saviors) (this link is used in my programm)

But it isn't work now because when I send request it returns null.

So why it's happen and how I could solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what usually happens:

- They check how many requests you make to the website.
- They usually have a certain restriction of how many requests you can
  make per minute.
- They might block you for some time if you do this too frequently.

It's an error know as 429.